# How to get selected data from SelectField in flask wtf

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

```
select = SelectField("City")

form.select.choices = [(places['name'], places['name']) for places in place]
```

Now I want to get selected data from selectfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the form class initializer method.

I am giving the example and clear explanation:

#### models.py

```
class Place(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True)
```

#### forms.py

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import SelectField

class PlaceForm(Form):
    name_list = SelectField(u'Choose the place')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name_list.choices = [(obj.id, obj.name) for obj in Place.query.order_by('name')]
```

#### in templates

```
 <div class="control-group{% if form.errors.name_list %} error{% endif %}">
                            {{ form.name_list(placeholder="--select--") }}
                            {% for error in form.errors.name_list %}
                                <span class="help-inline">{{error}}</span><br>
                            {% endfor %}

</div>
make sure you are passing the form to this template in your views.py.
```

This should work.I think you could understand this snippet well.